# Using regexp with sphinx

Tags: regex, sphinx, character-encoding

I need to make an algorythm that allows me to use uncertain (regexp) search in sphinx.

For example: i need to find a phrase that contains uncertain symbols: "2x4" maybe look like "2x4" or "2*4" or "2-4".

I want to do something like this: "2(x|*|-)4". But if i try to use this construction in query, sphinx split it on three words: "2", "(x|*|-)" and "4":

```
$ search -p "2x4"
...
index 'xxx': query '2x4 ': returned 25 matches of 25 total in 0.000 sec
...
words:
1. '2x4': 25 documents, 25 hits


$ search -p "2(x|y)4"
...
index 'xxx': query '2(x|y)4 ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. '2': 816 documents, 842 hits
2. 'x': 21 documents, 21 hits
3. 'y': 0 documents, 0 hits
4. '4': 2953 documents, 3014 hits
```

Like ugly hack I cat do something like (2x4)|(2*4)|(2-4), but this is not good solution if I get a big phrase like "2x4x2.2" and need "2(x|*|-)4(x|*|-)2(.|,)2".

I can use "charset_table" option to define "*>x","->x",",>." and so on, but this is not flexible decision.

Can you find a better solution?

ps: sorry for my english =)

Comment: The accepted answer is not entirely correct.  While RegEx cannot be used at search time, it can be used while building the index.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read, Sphinx doesn't support regex searches. Moreover, while the [extended syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/extended-syntax.html) (enabled with the `-e` option) has operators that support alternatives (the "OR" operator: |) and sequencing (the strict order operator: <<), they only work on words, not atoms, so that `2 << (x|*|-) << 4` would match strings where each element is a separate word, such as '2 x 4', '2 * 4'.

One option is to write a utility that converts a pattern of the form `2(x|*|-)4(x|*|-)2(.|,)2` (or, to follow the regex idiom, `2[-*x]4[-*x]2[.,]2`) into a Sphinx extended query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need atoms not words: "2x2" without spaces between...

Comment: @taofos: that's my point: Sphinx doesn't support the features you need, so you need a different approach, such as a utility to translate from regexes to Sphinx's extended query language.

Comment: Now I`m using mongo with regexp instead =) Much slower, but its not a problem for me...

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use regular expressions with Sphinx.

While they cannot be used at search time, they can be used while building the index to identify a group of words/symbols that should be considered to be the same token.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-regexp-filter

```
# index '13-inch' as '13inch'
regexp_filter = \b(\d+)\" => \1inch

# index 'blue' or 'red' as 'color'
regexp_filter = (blue|red) => color
```

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx indexes whole words - and 'tokenizes' the word into an integer that is then stored in the index. As such regular expressions can't work because dont have the original words.

However there is dict=keywords - which does store the words in an index. But this can only right now be used for * and ? wildcards, doesnt support regular expressions.

Also, perhaps could use the techniques discussed here
http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp4.html

This shows how generic regex searching can be implemented with a trigram index. Sphinx
itself would work as the trigram index. You store the trigrams as keywords which then
sphinx indexes. Sphinx can run the boolean queries taht that system outputs.

(normal sphinx, works pretty much like the 'Indexed Word Search' section documents. So
the trick would be using sphinx as the backend for the indexed Reg-Ex Search)